# Select latest row in LEFT JOIN PHP MySQL CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to achieve the following:
I have two tables. One of the tables is called `characters` and the other one is called `experience`. Right now I want to print a list of all `characters` and linking the latest row in `experience` to it. Added to that rows in `characters` without a row in `experience` should still be shown.

Here an example of the tables and desired output.

```
characters
id   |   name   |
----------------|
1    | TestChar |
2    | NewChar  |
3    | OldChar  |

experience
id |  char_id  |  experience  |
------------------------------|
1  |  1        | 683185858    |
2  |  2        | 85712849     |
3  |  1        | 687293919    |
4  |  1        | 794812393    |

output
name      |   experience   |
---------------------------|
TestChar  | 794812393      |
NewChar   | 85712849       |
OldChar   | NULL           |
```

So far, I made this query and it seems to work in MySQL

```
SELECT c.name, e1.experience
FROM characters c
LEFT JOIN experience e1 ON e1.char_id = c.id 
LEFT JOIN experience e2 ON e1.char_id = e2.char_id AND e2.id > e1.id
WHERE e2.id IS NULL;
```

Then, I want to implement this in CodeIgniter but that's where it goes wrong.
The following is what I have right now, it fills in the c.name but the e1.exp remains empty.

```
$this->db->select('c.name, e1.exp');
$this->db->from('characters as c');
$this->db->join('experience as e1', 'e1.char_id = c.id', 'left');
$this->db->join('experience as e2', 'e1.char_id = e2.char_id AND e2.id > e1.id', 'left');
$this->db->where('e2.id', NULL);
```

Is this related to my MySQL query being wrong? Is my implementation in CodeIgniter incorrect? Both?
I appreciate every bit of advice!

Comment: Try checking what SQL query CI generated (using `$this->db->last_query()`, I guess). Then let's see, if there is any difference.

Comment: Query generated is correct , **ITS A TYPO** `$this->db->select('c.name, e1.exp');` should be `$this->db->select('c.name, e1.experience');` because **There is no such column called exp, its experience**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a join condition that only selects the row the maximum `id` per `char_id`.

```
$this->db->select('c.name, e1.exp');
$this->db->from('characters as c');
$this->db->join('experience as e1', 'e1.id = (select max(id) from experience as e2 where e2.char_id = e1.char_id)', 'left');
```

or similarly using a derived table

```
$this->db->select('c.name, e1.exp');
$this->db->from('characters as c');
$this->db->join('(select max(id) max_id, char_id 
    from experience group by char_id) as t1', 't1.char_id = c.id', 'left')
$this->db->join('experience as e1', 'e1.id = t1.max_id', 'left')
```

Answer (score 1):

Roel you can use the sum method to find the results. In mysql it would be

```
SELECT c.name, SUM(e1.experience) as expsum
FROM characters c
LEFT JOIN experience e1 ON e1.char_id = c.id GROUP BY c.name
```

and when you are using in codeigniter you can try the following:-

```
$this->db->select("c.name, SUM(e1.exp) as 'expsum'");
$this->db->from('characters as c');
$this->db->join('experience as e1', 'e1.char_id = c.id', 'left');
$this->db->group_by("c.name"); 
$this->db->get();
$query->results_array();
```

Hope it helps